# Tkenv error in Omnet++ when running simulation in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, simulation, omnet++

I am trying to run a simulation in omnet++5.0.
I am using Ubuntu 16 in a virtualbox. Omnet++5.0 have been configured and compiled correctly but when I try to run some simulation I get the following error:
Error: Tkenv: too few arguments for math function "double".

I have no idea what is wrong. I have followed the installation manual very carefully. I would be very grateful if someone could try and help me.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not an error *with* Tkenv, that is just the graphical environment that shows you the error message.
My guess is that the ["double" function](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:ned-functions:category-conversion) is used incorrectly in either an `.ini`, or a `.ned` file.

We can only help you if you tell us exactly which simulation from which framework you try to run, in which configuration, what the complete error message is, and when does the error occur.